# How to achieve this layout configuration in Android View

Tags: android, android-layout

My current Android application requires a complex layout as follows.

this is the completed view

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                        |
|   --------------- ------------------------------------------------- ---------------    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |    IV(1)    | |                   TV(1)                       | |    IV(2)    |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   --------------- ------------------------------------------------- ---------------    |
|   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------    |
|   |                                                                               |    |
|   |                                                                               |    |
|   |                                                                               |    |
|   |                                   TV(2)                                       |    |
|   |                                                                               |    |
|   |                                                                               |    |
|   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------    |
|   --------------- ------------------------------------------------- ---------------    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |     IV(3)   | |                   TV(3)                       | |    IV(4)    |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   |             | |                                               | |             |    |
|   --------------- ------------------------------------------------- ---------------    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It consists of four `ImageView`s, (e.g. `IV1` - `4`) and three `TextView`s (e.g. `TV1` - `3`)

There are additional restrictions I have to adhere to

- A Minimum of 1 ImageView will always be present, it can be any of the
  four shown
- All textViews are mandatory
- All ImageViews have identical
  width & height
- All Textviews heights must match that of the
  ImageViews

For the Top and middle rows shown above I have managed to get to the following layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_row_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_left_corner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/top_left_corner"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/top_right_corner"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/top_left_corner"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_right_corner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/middle_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
```

I wanted to achieve the desired UI without having to develop a custom View, I've a feeling that it may be the only solution though.

Comment: I recommend you to learn about `ConstraintLayout` and use horizontal and vertical bias on the child views, that might be how you can achieve it.

Comment: @Gourav im not a big fan of ConstraintLayout, however I'll give it a go

Comment: Even I wasn't a fan until I learned it. It can be helpful in a lot many scenarios. Worth learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this layout using `ConstraintLayout`

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clMain1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMain1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivMain1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivMain2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivMain1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivMain1"
            android:text="Text1"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMain2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clMain1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clMain2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text2"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clMain2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMain3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivMain3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivMain4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivMain3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivMain3"
            android:text="Text3"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMain4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For more info for `ContraintLayout` Check this official [link](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enbq5.png) for above code

Comment: You sped my constraint learning, im coming round to the way of thinking constraint layout is not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about `ConstraintLayout` or `TableLayout`, these two arrangements can solve your problem.